# Potential Connection Between Search Console Issues and Storyblok?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

First, I'm generally more familiar with WordPress, and my company uses Storyblok as our headless CMS. I'm generally less familiar with headless and so I'm assuming there may be a connection here.

Google Search Console has been producing warnings for non-indexed pages that don't exist. There are two specific groupings that I'm interested in:

1. Pages that are not published and therefore, presumably, can not be crawled
2. Pages that exist on a second domain only, but are being discovered as belonging to the first domain

Clarifying point 2: My team owns `ABC.example`. Our sister company, `XYZ.example`, has a single page `XYZ.example/abc/special-page` which we operate and is built on the same Storyblok instance. Search Console is discovering `ABC.example/abc/special-page`, which does not exist.

It's worth noting that GSC also discovers templates and out of the box demo pages from Storyblok, which also have never been published, linked to, or added to a sitemap.

Any idea what could be causing these issues, and what the best way to resolve them is? Is there any real problem with having these warnings, since they're not intended to be indexed anyway (since they're not real)?